# Modifying an anonymous function to invoke another anonymous function in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I have few click listeners in my code like below:

```
tvLogin.setOnClickListener {
    hideKeyBoard(it)
    login()
}

tvForgotPassword.setOnClickListener {
    hideKeyBoard(it)
    navigateToForgetPassword()
}
```

I want to modify the passed block of code to always invoke `hideKeyBoard(view)` and then my function.

Is there a way to create a higher order function that would modify a block of code and invoke passed function?

I have tried something like below:

```
val clickListener: (View,()->Unit) -> Unit
```

But not sure how it would work.

Can anyone please help how to achieve?

Comment: Can you edit the `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: @Sweeper No it is the part of Android framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you mean, but maybe something like this:

```
fun addCallTo(lambda: (View) -> Unit): (View) -> Unit {
  return { 
    hideKeyboard(it)
    lambda(it)
  }
}

// usage:
tvLogin.setOnClickListener(addCallTo { view -> login() })
```

Comment: why does this function return?

Comment: @agile1 added usage example.

Comment: @agile1 The function will return another function. The returned function will call `hideKeyboard` and the parameter passed in. So you can pass the return value of `addCallTo` to `setOnClickListener`. Which part confuses you?

Comment: I am confused with why did you return the function. Can't we just return unit?

Comment: or maybe an extension function

Comment: should I inline it?

Comment: It isn't invoking lambda

Comment: @krupal.agile sure you should inline

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `View.OnClickListener` and pass lambda to it:

```
inner class HideKeyboardClickListener(private val lambda: () -> Unit) : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        hideKeyboard(v)
        lambda()
    }
}
```

And then set it like this:

```
tvForgotPassword.setOnClickListener(HideKeyboardClickListener {
    navigateToForgetPassword()
})
```