# Weird behaviour of higher order functions and SAM conversion in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, kotlin, higher-order-functions

This question relates to my previous question : [Modifying an anonymous function to invoke another anonymous function in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693148)

I wrote a function that will modify the click listener as given in the answers:

```
fun modifiedClick( onClick: (View) -> Unit): (View) -> Unit {
        return {
            //hide keyboard and invoke click only if there is a gap between frequent clicks
            hideKeyBoard(it)
            if (!isClickDisabled) {
                onClick(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Now if I call it like below:

```
view.setOnClickListener {modifiedClick { login() }}
```

It does not invoke `login()`

But If I change SAM conversion to normal like below:

```
view.setOnClickListener (modifiedClick { login() })
```

It works!

Also, if I inline the function like below:

```
inline fun modifiedClick(crossline onClick: (View) -> Unit): (View) -> Unit {
            return {
                //hide keyboard and invoke click only if there is a gap between frequent clicks
                hideKeyBoard(it)
                if (!isClickDisabled) {
                    onClick(it)
                }
            }
        }
```

and call like below:

```
view.setOnClickListener {modifiedClick { login() }}
```

It isn't even invoking `modifiedClick`.

Changing it to

```
view.setOnClickListener (modifiedClick { login() })
```

is invoking both `modifiedClick()` and then `login()` functions.

Can anyone help me to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

```
view.setOnClickListener {modifiedClick { login() }}
```

Here you wrote a shorthand for this (I'm paraphrasing the type/function names):

```
view.setOnClickListener(object : OnClickListener() {
    override fun onClick(e: ClickEvent) {
        modifiedClick { login() }
    }
})
```

It's a listener that, on click, calls your `modifiedClick` method, which creates and returns the modified listener. The listener it returns is simply ignored and no observable effect happens.

As opposed to that, when you wrote

```
view.setOnClickListener(modifiedClick { login() })
```

you simply called `modifiedClick { login() }` and passed its return value to `setOnClickListener` — which is what you wanted to do.

Comment: Didn't understand really. if there is only single method, then how does this work differently? I'm not really a functional programmer. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: You don't need to be a functional programmer for this, you just need to know how lambda expressions work - either in Kotlin or in Java

Comment: I tried to make it even more explicit in the updated answer.

Comment: ok, so, if you specify with braces, then does it return the click listener?

Comment: and is there any explanation about inline?

Comment: `inline` doesn't change any semantics. The function's return value doesn't change.

Comment: `if you specify with braces`---specify _what_ with braces? In my answer I deal with the case where you specify the entire listener within a pair of braces and discuss its meaning.